# Matplotlib error when stacking two bar plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two bar plots together, one drawn above the other. However, when I make the call to create the graphs, I am getting the error:

"TypeError: inner() got multiple values for argument 'ax'"

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize = (8,4))
plt.bar(range(len(pmfList)), pmfList, ax = axes[0])
plt.bar(range(len(uList)), uList, ax = axes[1])
plt.show()
```

Am I passing something in wrong? This issue only occurs when I using the axes- they graph fine individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) does not have an `ax` keyword argument.

In order to plot to different axes,

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize = (8,4))
axes[0].bar(range(len(pmfList)), pmfList)
axes[1].bar(range(len(uList)), uList)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hooray! Thanks for your time! That did what I was hoping to do.